# Why do rsync processes keep running even after killed by Ctrl-C?

Tags: backup, process, rsync

I am running a rsync process to sync my files to a remote location. The I/O loads are pretty high, mostly in accessing the remote location. The local location is the machine disk.

I killed the rsync process (using Ctrl-C) a number of times to accommodate other tasks.

Now, a while ago I was simply checking something and found that *all* the rsync processes, started after the machine reboot, are running in D state.

[image]

As is delineated [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/508576/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-r-d-flag-in-ps-output),

> A process in a D state will not handle signals straight away as it's
> currently stuck waiting for disk (usually, and this is where the
> letter D in the code comes from). This would indicate an issue if the
> process is stuck for a longer period of time or if multiple processes
> are in the same state. The problem is then probably related to high
> I/O load (too many processes wanting to read from a too slow disk, for
> example).

A little more exploration shows.

[image]

The above indicates that the streams are still open.

As I have already pointed out, this rsync task involves a pretty high I/O load (heavy writing to Google Drive). But does this mean that the streams can not be closed after several hours?

When a kill command was issued (`killall -KILL rsync`), the processes went away without the slightest indication of complaint.

Am I making a mistake by killing using Ctrl-C?

What could be the best way to handle the needs of occasional termination of rsync processes?

What could be other measures to improve the overall scenario?

Comment: Depends on what outcome you want. See this resource for an explanation: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/can-rsync-resume-after-being-interrupted.

Comment: How's your swap usage and copy speed?  ctrl-C is just one of the (many) maskable signals which may be trapped and handled any way the program wants. The non-maskable signal (KILL?) eliminates any possibility of letting the program end gracefully (like flush it's buffers).  Try the nocache rsync... to control the buffer buildup, and maybe improve copy speed and allow reasonable ctrl-C termination.

Comment: @ubfan1 Swap space usage is very minimal. In fact, out of available 32G, only 500K is being used. Do you still recommend using nocache?

Comment: Try it, when system buffers fill up, the throughput may drop to the 10s of K.  That may take a long time to flush, which seems to be what you are seeing. Ideally, you should be able to add userspace buffers to rsync, like tar or cpio offers. Not sure that's doable however.

Comment: @ubfan1 Using nocache as suggested. I can not claim that I notice any appreciable change except that, free shows zero swap space usage. Do you recommend any other diagnostic to check the overall scenario?